# How to make the right API call?

Tags: swift

I am trying to access fixer.io by making an API call. It is the first time than I am trying to do so, but I don't get the result wanted. I would like to get the "rate" and the "result" from this JSON file.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "query": {
        "from": "GBP",
        "to": "JPY",
        "amount": 25
    },
    "info": {
        "timestamp": 1519328414,
        "rate": 148.972231
    },
    "historical": ""
    "date": "2018-02-22"
    "result": 3724.305775
}
```

The method that I have implemented is this one, but I can not figure out how to retrieve "rate" and "result" when making this API call.

```
extension APIsRuler {
  func getExchangeRate(from: String, to: String, amount: String, callback: @escaping (Bool, ConversionResult?) -> Void) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: APIsRuler.exchangeURL)
    let body = "convert?access_key=\(APIsRuler.exchangeAPI)&from=\(from)&to=\(to)&amount=\(amount)"
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

    task?.cancel()
    task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
          return callback(false, nil)
        }
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
          return callback(false, nil)
        }
        guard let responseJSON = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String: Double].self, from: data),
          let rate = responseJSON["rate"],
          let result = responseJSON["result"] else {
            return callback(false, nil)
        }
        let conversionResult = ConversionResult(exchangeRate: rate, exchangeResult: result)
        callback(true, conversionResult)
      }
    }
    task?.resume()
  }
}
```

Comment: `let rate = responseJSON["rate"],` is nil, and that's why it fails. If you are new, don' do `guard let 1, let 2, let 3 else {}`, do `guard let 1 else {} guard let 2 else {}`. In other words, in multiple lines guard, you can know which one failed, and by debugging (breakpoint, printing values), you might find what you missed.

Comment: First of all, if you do this first time, I recommend you to use Alamofire + SwiftyJSON libraries. 

0, Install CocoaPods if you didn't do that before

1, Install Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

  [1]: https://cocoapods.org
  [2]: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire
  [3]: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: @Dris I disagree. Why pods, why Alamofire, why SwiftyJSON? Basically `URLSession` is perfectly fine for such a simple task and all third-party JSON parsers have become obsolete in favor of the `Codable` protocol

Comment: I totally missed the real error. `decode([String: Double].self`, that's the one which should fail. It should be `[String: Any]`. Don't silence the `try` with `try?`. Use a do/catch. For Swift 4+, read about Codable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up two different APIs.

1. Either use **`JSONSerialization`**, the result is a dictionary and you get the values by key and index subscription. And you have to downcast every type and consider the nested `rate` value.

   ```
   guard let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any],
         let info = responseJSON["info"] as? [String:Any],
         let rate = info["rate"] as? Double,
         let result = responseJSON["result"] as? Double else {
             return callback(false, nil)
   }
   let conversionResult = ConversionResult(exchangeRate: rate, exchangeResult: result)
   callback(true, conversionResult)
   ```
2. Or use **`JSONDecoder`** then you have to create structs, decoding to `[String:Double]` can work only if **all** values in the root object are `Double` which is clearly not the case.

   ```
   struct Root: Decodable {
       let info: Info
       let result: Double
   }

   struct Info: Decodable {
       let rate: Double
   }

   guard let responseJSON = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data) else {
       return callback(false, nil)
   }
   let conversionResult = ConversionResult(exchangeRate: responseJSON.info.rate, exchangeResult: responseJSON.result)
   callback(true, conversionResult)
   ```

---

The code is only an example to keep your syntax. Practically you are strongly discouraged from using `try?` when decoding JSON. Always `catch` and handle errors

```
do {
    let responseJSON = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    let conversionResult = ConversionResult(exchangeRate: responseJSON.info.rate, exchangeResult: responseJSON.result)
   callback(true, conversionResult)
} catch {
    print(error)
    return callback(false, nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a real model object, like this:

```
struct Conversion: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let query: Query
    let info: Info
    let historical, date: String
    let result: Double
}

struct Info: Codable {
    let timestamp: Int
    let rate: Double
}

struct Query: Codable {
    let from, to: String
    let amount: Int
}
```

and parse your response into it using `JSONDecoder`:

```
do {
  let conversion = try JSONDecoder().decode(Conversion.self, from: data)
  let rate = conversion.info.rate
  let result = conversion.result
} catch { print(error) }
```